# Run docker container with sh from command line

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

docker beginner here, I have an assignment to create a Dockerfile that can make my app to be run this way:

```
docker build -t newapp .
docker run -v $(pwd):/app -p 8080:8080 -w /app newapp ./start.sh
```

I was creating something like this:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install
COPY . .
```

but I end up with this:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: 11: exec: ./run.sh: Permission denied
```

I also tried putting my sh scripts in scripts folder and adding

```
RUN chmod +x ./scripts/*
```

but it fails

Comment: Why does your proposed `docker run` command overwrite the image's `/app` directory with a bind mount (so nothing you do in the Dockerfile actually has an effect)?  Should the image have a `CMD` to run?

Comment: not sure about what you mean, but the image should not have a cmd to run just because in the assignment the user is running ```docker run -v $(pwd):/app -p 8080:8080 -w /app newapp ./start.sh```to run the dockerfile also this  command they are changing the files in the main folder

Comment: Given that `docker run` command I'd expect you'd get the same result if you used the unmodified Node image (`docker run -v ... -p ... -w /app node:16 ./start.sh`).  There's not a lot of benefit to using Docker in this setup

Comment: I agree but this is just an assignment

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change the Dockerfile into:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install
COPY . .

RUN chmod +x ./scripts/*
```